# Python Remove element from json if value exists

Tags: python, json, geojson

I have a rather large geojson file which is converted from some National Weather Service data. I've trimmed it down to this sample here:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "name": "day1otlk"
  },
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -122.71424459627099,
              40.229695635383166
            ],
            [
              -122.62484780364827,
              40.53410620541074
            ],
            [
              -122.71424459627099,
              40.229695635383166
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Name": "General Thunder",
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "stroke-width": 4,
        "name": "General Thunder",
        "fill": "#c0e8c0",
        "fill-opacity": 0.75,
        "stroke": "#ffffff",
        "timeSpan": {
          "end": "2017-03-30T12:00:00Z",
          "begin": "2017-03-29T20:00:00Z"
        }
      },
      "type": "Feature"
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -108.65861565996833,
              32.91391108773154
            ],
            [
              -108.63932601964923,
              32.95521185698698
            ],
            [
              -108.65861565996833,
              32.91391108773154
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Name": "General Thunder",
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "stroke-width": 4,
        "name": "General Thunder",
        "fill": "#c0e8c0",
        "fill-opacity": 0.75,
        "stroke": "#ffffff",
        "timeSpan": {
          "end": "2017-03-30T12:00:00Z",
          "begin": "2017-03-29T20:00:00Z"
        }
      },
      "type": "Feature"
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -92.67280213157608,
              38.47870651780003
            ],
            [
              -92.62448390998837,
              38.45534960370862
            ],
            [
              -92.59475154780039,
              38.493327413824595
            ],
            [
              -92.64308574626148,
              38.51669676139087
            ],
            [
              -92.67280213157608,
              38.47870651780003
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Name": "10 %",
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "stroke-width": 4,
        "name": "10 %",
        "fill": "#8b4726",
        "fill-opacity": 0.89,
        "stroke": "#ffffff",
        "timeSpan": {
          "end": "2017-03-30T12:00:00Z",
          "begin": "2017-03-29T20:00:00Z"
        }
      },
      "type": "Feature"
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -92.67280213157608,
              38.47870651780003
            ],
            [
              -92.62448390998837,
              38.45534960370862
            ],
            [
              -92.59475154780039,
              38.493327413824595
            ],
            [
              -92.64308574626148,
              38.51669676139087
            ],
            [
              -92.67280213157608,
              38.47870651780003
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Name": "10 %",
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "stroke-width": 4,
        "name": "20 %",
        "fill": "#8b4726",
        "fill-opacity": 0.89,
        "stroke": "#ffffff",
        "timeSpan": {
          "end": "2017-03-30T12:00:00Z",
          "begin": "2017-03-29T20:00:00Z"
        }
      },
      "type": "Feature"
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -97.09845994557838,
              38.43843745045377
            ],
            [
              -97.07114801649661,
              38.47751978088534
            ],
            [
              -97.09845994557838,
              38.43843745045377
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Name": "5 %",
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "stroke-width": 4,
        "name": "5 %",
        "fill": "#b47f00",
        "fill-opacity": 0.89,
        "stroke": "#ffffff",
        "timeSpan": {
          "end": "2017-03-30T12:00:00Z",
          "begin": "2017-03-29T20:00:00Z"
        }
      },
      "type": "Feature"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm looking to remove the elements where `name` has a `%` in it. I don't want those coordinates or anything included.

Here's my code:

```
import json

with open('test.geojson') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for element in data["features"]:
    if '%' in element["properties"]["name"]:
        del element["type"]
        del element["properties"] # Deletes the properties
        del element["geometry"] # Deletes the  coords


with open('test_output.geojson', 'w') as data_file:
    data = json.dump(data, data_file)
```

This works well enough to remove the element's sub keys, but I'm left with output that looks like:

`{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}`

I've also tried to use

```
for element in data["features"]:
        if '%' in element["properties"]["name"]:
                    data["features"].remove(element)
```

but that seems to delete only the last element in the sample group, which is the `5 %` group. It should be removing the `10 %`, `20 %` and the `5 %` groups.

Is there a way to remove the element from `data["features"]` if `name` has a `%` in it all together so I'm left with clean json output? In this sample data, the only `data["features"]` I should have left are the `General Thunder` and no empty brackets.

Comment: Rather than deleting elements, could you not create a new filtered JSON? Like `new_data = {elem for elem in data if '%' not in elem['properties']['name']}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with using `del element["type"]`, `del element["properties"]` and `del element["geometry"]` is that it only removes those items from properties dict of that element. Not the element itself.

For your 2nd item, when you're iterating over a list like in `for element in data["features"]:`, it's not good to modify a list or object while iterating over it (which is what's happening with `data["features"].remove(element)`). Also, [`list.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) removes an item with that *value*. So `element` gets used in a value context, not as *that element*.

It's better to create a new list and then assign that. What you could do is:

```
new_features = []
for element in data["features"]:
    if '%' not in element["properties"]["name"]:    # note the 'not'
        new_features.append(element)                # new_features has the one's you want
# and then re-assign features to the list with the elements you want
data["features"] = new_features
```

Comment: FWIW, the list comprehension method in @triptych's answer is the way I would have done it, had I not been lacking coffee & sleep. It avoids assigning the unneeded `new_features` list, and is faster.

Answer (score 4):

Use a simple filter:

```
no_percent = lambda feature: '%' not in feature['properties']['name']
data['features'] = filter(no_percent, data['features'])
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
data['features'] = [feature for feature in data['features']
                      if '%' not in feature['properties']['name']]
```

Comment: So much more Pythonic to use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) instead.

Comment: It's worth noting that in Python 3 `filter` returns an iterator.  You would need to `data['features'] = list(filter(...))`

Comment: This is a great method too, one I'm not familiar with yet - but a great example to continue learning! Thank you